# Binning the data & plotting the histogram

Tags: r, statistics, python-2.7, data-analysis

I have a list of values (these are positive as well as negative values). As an example say I have 35000 numbers (+ve and -ve both in it).

What I want to do is to bin them, i.e. the number values between 0-200 (also from -200 to 0), 201-400 (-400 to 201), .... and so on till 48,800-50000 (-50000 to 48,500).

Once I have these values, the plotting of histogram or any other representation is easier. I can take this to excel or plot it in python or PERL or R.

But first stage itself is bit tricky.

As an example, you may consider following data:

```
 -9030
   -75
  8005
  -251
 65994
-12111
-11643
 19749
-23324
 10012
   -77
```

Thank you

Comment: `cut` or `hist` will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(12345)
n <- 35000
dataset <- data.frame(Number = runif(n, min = -200, max = 50000))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Number)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 200)
```

giving

[image]

Comment: @Angelo - the kind folks who maintain R have written an entire manual dedicated to these sorts of questions. You can peruse it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html).